# Prevent authorization popup when using SMJobBless

Tags: objective-c, security, cocoa

we are developing an application with a Helper Tool - which is installed into the system using SMJobBless. This works as expected; but there is a caveat.

We do frequent automatic deployments - sometimes more than one per week. Everytime the Helper Tool version changes, we re-register it - causing a password prompt. These 2 factors would quickly become irritating to our users.

Is there a way to have the password prompt appear only once, during the initial Helper Tool installation? Could subsequent updates happen without a prompt? Perhaps there is a way to leverage the existing Helper Tool to install a newer version of itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. `SMJobBless()` always prompts for admin credentials. There's no way to stop it from prompting. If you call this API, it'll prompt (or fail).

---

Longer answer on workarounds:

If your helper tool is running with admin/root privileges, it could theoretically replace itself with a new version. **Think very carefully before doing this.** Getting this right and maintaining security is **very difficult**, and the fact that even the major OSes have had [vulnerabilities](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2015-5754/) in [installer functionality](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS15-074) is a strong indicator that the risks of going this route may outweigh the benefits.

If you must proceed, read up on:

- [Race Conditions, Secure File Operations, and Time of Check vs Time of Use](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/RaceConditions.html)
- Apple's [Security APIs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security), particularly [`SecRequirementCreateWithString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1394522-secrequirementcreatewithstring) and [`SecCodeCheckValidity`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1396726-seccodecheckvalidity).
- [macOS Code Signing In Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html) and the [Code Signing Requirement Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/RequirementLang/RequirementLang.html)

You would have to ensure that your helper tool cannot be tricked into replacing itself with (or executing) malicious code, or you will have opened your software up to being a trivial root exploit vector.

Also note: Regardless of what Apple currently does to verify helper tools installed by `SMJobBless`, it is conceivable that they could tighten the requirements in the future and refuse to run helper tools that have been modified since they were installed via `SMJobBless`. The safest method (in multiple respects) is to just call `SMJobBless` whenever you need to install/update the helper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially for the links. We'll go with the current solution for our users, but those workarounds will be useful in our integration tests.